# Insert empty string value in a foreign key field

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have an error when trying to insert values with a `''` in the foreign key field.

I use PostgreSQL v10.

My sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE meas_name (
    nopol varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    cchim varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    ncon varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (nopol)
);

CREATE TABLE main_device (
    ntypapp smallint NOT NULL,
    no_main smallint NOT NULL,
    lib_main varchar(25),
    nopol varchar(2),
    no_chrono smallint,
    PRIMARY KEY (no_main,ntypapp)
);

ALTER TABLE main_device ADD CONSTRAINT fk_maindevice_measname FOREIGN KEY (nopol) REFERENCES meas_name(nopol) ON DELETE NO ACTION NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
```

When i insert something in measure with a known deviceno I have this error:

```
insert into main_device values 
(1, 1, 'TST LASER','',1578)

ERROR: insert or update on table « main_device » violates foreign key constraint « fk_maindevice_measname »
DETAIL: Key (nopol) = () is not present in table « meas_name ».
```

I have tested it on: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fBnNSYWU8qZwFbmEoU5dce/1

There was no issue on Oracle database, but I don't know much about Postgres, Is there any limitation? How can I manage this?

Comment: You have "no issue on Oracle database", because Oracle considers the empty string ( '' )  the same as Null. Postgres considers them as different things.

Comment: @Belayer: it not only "considers" them the same, it actually stores `null` if you send an empty string.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant by considering them the same.  They are the same, everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

An empty string is not `NULL`.  Use `NULL`:

```
insert into main_device (ntypapp, no_main, lib_main, nopol, no_chrono)
    values (1, 1, 'TST LASER', NULL, 1578);
```

A `NULL` value does not need to match the foreign key constraint (in this context, `NULL` means "no value").  However, an empty string is a valid value and the database expects a matching row in the referenced table.

I also added the explicit column names because that is a best-practice.